# Build extjs from ext-all only for the tree

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using extjs version 3.2.1. From the extjs I am only using the tree to render a tree. I now got the ext-all.js loaded everytime and I was wondering if I could extract the functionality only needed for the tree to render from the ext-all to make it smaller?

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

In your download of ExtJS there is a `pkgs` directory which contains some prebuilt parts. If you are only using TreePanel, including these files should be enough:

```
pkgs/ext-foundation.js
pkgs/cmp-foundation.js
pkgs/pkg-tree.js
```

Comment: Much appreciated! I am going to try this out and get back to you!

Answer (score 0):

ExtJS is complex solution - Tree is one of advanced widget using many of components that inhered from many objects. Trying to extract just Tree from ext-all.js if successfull will save you 20-30% of file (my raw estimate) and amount of work and time spend on testing makes it completly not worted - my suggestion - drop that idea !